# Regenerar contraseña cliente Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Tengo una duda con Prestashop 1.6, necesito regenerar la contraseña del cliente si éste lo solicita.

Se que al seleccionar la opción **¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?,** envía un e-mail con un LINK que en teoría regenera la contraseña. El problema es que el link que genera, tiene problemas, no se muestra la página y redirecciona al Back-office.

Entonces, quisiera saber, ¿existe la posibilidad de que los pasos sean menos?, es decir al solicitar el cambio de contraseña, el e-mail que se recibe ya tenga la contraseña generada.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no está relacionada con programación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrias que hacer un override de la clase `\controllers\front\PasswordController.php`. De hecho el comportamiento por defecto si el cliente esta autenticado es ese: regenerar la contraseña y enviarla por email. El problema de esto con clientes no autenticados es que si lo haces asi, entonces yo pudiera entrar a la tienda y sabiendo el email del cliente regenerarle la contraseña, aun cuando el no lo haya solicitado.
Si aun con este problema de seguridad es este el comportamiento que quieres reproducir en tu tienda el codigo que necesitas esta en la funcion `postProcess` del fichero que antes de comente y seria el siguiente:

```
        $email = $email = trim(Tools::getValue('email'));
        if ($email) {
            $customer = new Customer();
            $customer->getByemail($email);
            if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($customer)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Customer account not found');
            } elseif (!$customer->active) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You cannot regenerate the password for this account.');
            } elseif ((strtotime($customer->last_passwd_gen.'+'.(int)Configuration::get('PS_PASSWD_TIME_FRONT').' minutes') - time()) > 0) {
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication&error_regen_pwd');
            } else {
                $customer->passwd = Tools::encrypt($password = Tools::passwdGen(MIN_PASSWD_LENGTH, 'RANDOM'));
                $customer->last_passwd_gen = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
                if ($customer->update()) {
                    Hook::exec('actionPasswordRenew', array('customer' => $customer, 'password' => $password));
                    $mail_params = array(
                        '{email}' => $customer->email,
                        '{lastname}' => $customer->lastname,
                        '{firstname}' => $customer->firstname,
                        '{passwd}' => $password
                    );
                    if (Mail::Send($this->context->language->id, 'password', Mail::l('Your new password'), $mail_params, $customer->email, $customer->firstname.' '.$customer->lastname)) {
                        $this->context->smarty->assign(array('confirmation' => 1, 'customer_email' => $customer->email));
                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while sending the email.');
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred with your account, which prevents us from sending you a new password. Please report this issue using the contact form.');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('We cannot regenerate your password with the data you\'ve submitted.');
        }
```

Buena suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias @PrestaAlba.  Si lo sé, es que no he logrado arreglar el link que se envía por defecto.  Probaré con esta función si va bien entonces ya haré dos procesos para la generación de contraseña.